# little confuse about optionals in swift

Tags: swift, optional-variables

Maybe I'm very confused idk yet. I thought i understood the basic concept but when playing around in xcode I'm not getting what I thought I should be
Take the following code

```
var title: String? = "hello world"
println("\(title)")
```

I thought that this would give me an error because I thought that title should have to be unwrapped since I;m accessing it, but it seems to compile just fine. Can someone shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

Optionals are `Printable`s, meaning you can print them to an output stream (here the console). You should see something like `Optional("hello world")` in your console and not `hello world`

Comment: Ok, I understand but i still dont understand then when would this have to be unwrapped

Comment: Have to be unwrapped when you want to use the actual value contained in the optional. Think that an `Optional` is a new type. For example, you cannot concat an `Optional<String>` with a `String`, it's not the same type. So you need to unwrap it in order to get your actual `String` in order to concat it with other `String`

Comment: Sure, I do get that but for example if I make the title of an alert view which takes a String, set to my optional title that also works fine without unwrapping.

Comment: It work because `UIAlertView` has an initializer that takes optionals as parameters : `init(title title: String?, message message: String?, delegate delegate: AnyObject?, cancelButtonTitle cancelButtonTitle: String?)`

Comment: THANKS! Big ups to you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

All an optional is is that if it is nil, the app won't crash. If you put the elimination mark, and did not assign a value, it would crash.

In an if statement, you can check if the variable is nil:

```
if (title == nil) {

//this works

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var title: String? = "hello world"
println("\(title)") // This would print out Optional(Title)
var title2: String! = "hello world"
println("\(title2)") // This would print in Title
```

Optional do not cause your program to crash when they are executed without a value but !(variable) will cause your code to crash if they have no value.

[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334):

> As described above, optionals indicate that a constant or variable is allowed to have “no value”. Optionals can be checked with an if statement to see if a value exists, and can be conditionally unwrapped with optional binding to access the optional’s value if it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, your statement will be converted to

```
var title: Optional<String> = Some("hello world").
```

From Apple documentation, Optional is

```
enum Optional<A> {
case Nil
case Some(A)
}
```

So when you are passing a value to an optional, at the time of declaration, compiler understands, it has got a value and that's why it is not showing error.

But if you do the below code you may get different result.

```
var title: String? = "hello world"
title = nil
println("\(title)")
```

It will print "nil" in playground.

Answer (score 0):

Based on apple doc

> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The
>   nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a
>   method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the
>   absence of a valid object.” However, this only works for objects—it
>   doesn’t work for structures, basic C types, or enumeration values. For
>   these types, Objective-C methods typically return a special value
>   (such as NSNotFound) to indicate the absence of a value. This approach
>   assumes that the method’s caller knows there is a special value to
>   test against and remembers to check for it. Swift’s optionals let you
>   indicate the absence of a value for any type at all, without the need
>   for special constants.

Example

```
let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
let forcedString: String = possibleString! // requires an exclamation mark

let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
let implicitString: String = assumedString // no need for an exclamation mark
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html